# In Javascript, how to differntiate objects which are saved with actual data and objects saved as reference?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Consider I have a object mainObj and I duplicating this object and saving in two other variables ObjD and ObjR.

```
mainObj = {x:1};

ObjR = mainObj;

ObjD = {};

mainAbjArray = Object.keys(mainObj);

for(i=0;i<mainAbjArray.length;i++){
ObjD[mainAbjArray[i]] = mainObj[mainAbjArray[i]];
}
```

After above execution, I have two objects when accessed gives sane data but the way of storage is different. So, how to find out if a object is saved as a reference (like ObjR) and saved with actual data (like ObjD)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjR` is not precisely an object, it is a name whose value is an object. That value happens to be identical to the value of the name `mainObj`. The value in question is `{x: 1}`. Anywhere in your program, writing `mainObj` or `ObjR` is semantically identical to writing `{x: 1}`. The former are names; the latter is a literal object. There is no way to distinguish between the two; in fact, the question is somewhat meaningless.

It is not the case that some objects are "saved with actual data" and others are "saved as reference". An object itself is just an object, the actual data comprising the object. A name is not an object, but rather can be thought of as a kind of pointer to an actual object. Names never point to other names; they point to values.

`ObjR = mainObj;` does not mean "set `ObjR` to refer to `mainObj`". It means "set the value of `ObjR` to the current value of `mainObj`". `ObjR` has no connection whatsoever with the variable `mainObj`.

Confusion can arise because in normal conversation we do say things like "the object `ObjR`". You need to keep in mind that this a sort of shorthand for saying "the object to which the variable named `ObjR` refers."

Consider a simpler example with numbers:

```
a = 1;
b = a;
```

Now, can I distinguish between `a` and `b`? No. Why would I want to?

Comment: The reason why i asked this question is, as a part of an interview I was asked to pass a parameter to a function and the parameter is an array having many objects. Of these objects, few may be created like 'ObjR' in above example and other like 'ObjD'. So the function should remove all the objects created like 'ObjR' and return only objects like 'ObjD'. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, there is not. Either this was a trick question, **or** the language was not JavaScript, **or** the company you are interviewing with is deeply confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Objects are always saved as a reference.

You can copy them about. `mainObj` and `ObjR` contain identical values. There is no way to distinguish them.

`ObjD` is just another reference to another object which you've made identical by copying all the values across.

You can distinguish between the two objects with `==` because they are different objects, but you can't tell how the object was created or the variable was populated.